# glGetError returns 1282 infinitely

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is my function for logging errors:

```
void check_error(const char* st)
{
    GLenum err(glGetError());

    while (err != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "OpenGL error: " << err << " "<<st<<endl;
        err = glGetError();
    }
    cerr << "?\n";
}
```

It's called this way:

```
int _tmain(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    check_error("start");
    ...
}
```

It's not called anywhere else.

It produces:
`OpenGL error 1282 start` in infinite loop.

Here are my includes:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <GL/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
```

Visual studio 2013

Comment: If you don't have a valid GL context (GL window for example), the GL might simply return `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` (0x502 = 1282).

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer; but in lieu of your comment, I have a function in my GL library:

```
GLenum
G0::glFlushError () // noexcept
{
    GLenum ret = glGetError();

    if (ret != GL_NO_ERROR)
    {
        GLuint finite = 255; // (watchdog count)
        GLenum gl_err = ret;

        while (gl_err != GL_NO_ERROR && finite--)
            gl_err = glGetError();

        if (gl_err != GL_NO_ERROR)
            G0::terminate("glGetError: reset failed\n");
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Where `G0` is my library's namespace. When you want to test the most recent GL error - and clear it - `glGetError` needs to be called in a [loop](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetError.xhtml). It's an 'expensive' call, as it stalls the pipeline, and therefore should only be used in 'setup' code, or during debugging.

Comment: And for obvious reasons - I moved the library namespace to: `GL0` - `G0` being too close to a language that Rust hasn't vanquished yet...

Comment: you're allowed to have things with similar names to other things. You don't have to make up weird names for everything

Comment: @user253751 - It strikes me as *less* weird, given its purpose. But you do you mate.